# CAML and External List - pass parameter to ReadList (finder) method

Tags: caml-query, bcs

I have a Finder method defined on an External Content type (created with Visual Studio). Whan That method receives a parameter. So the method is something like ReadList(string partnerName). I have FilterDescriptor associated with this parameter so the parameter gets populated when I use Entity Picker dialog.

But When I use CAML Query to get items (using SharePoint Client Object Model) I can't get to call the ReadList method with a parameter. An example of my CAML Query is

```
<View>
    <Method Name='ReadList'/>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='Name'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Name'/>
    <FieldRef Name='Id'/>
    <FieldRef Name='BdcIdentity'/>                        
    </ViewFields>
</View>
```

Setting breakpoint on my BCS assembly I see that indeed ReadList method is called, but parameter is empty. Is it possible to pass the parameter to the method as well?

Comment: I have a question on above post. that is, in the filter you specified the values as **{0}** <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value> So here how we can send a dynamic value in the place of **{0}** My requirement is to filter the data based on query string value Please answer my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, @Vasu. It's quite simple. If you're doing this in C# and you have a page, then you can do it very simple. You just put the query above in the String.Format. An example would be `String.Format(@"<View><Method Name=...", Request.QueryString["PartnerName"]);`. If you're doing it in JavaScript, you need to make a function for querystring (you can find one on [my blog](http://www.sharepointboris.net/js/library) (search for qs). Next you put the CAML query in a variable (for example `var query = "<View><Method Name=...";' and next you do a `query = query.replace(/\{0\}/g, qs("partner"));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it!

```
<View>
    <Method Name='ReadList'>
        <Filter Name='PartnerName' Value='{0}'/>
    </Method>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='Name'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Name'/>
    <FieldRef Name='Id'/>
    <FieldRef Name='BdcIdentity'/>                        
    </ViewFields>
</View>
```

Be sure to replace the filter Name attribute value with your own FilterDescriptor name as defined in BCS model and Value attribute with your own value.

Comment: Brilliant stuff, this is exactly what I've been looking for all day!

Comment: Hi, can you explain me what filter type did you use?

Comment: I've used FilterDescriptor of type Comparison